# Can't show a value in my page that i get from my controller using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is a part of my JSP file where I have a problem :

```
<div class="aimerSection">
     <div class="aime">
         <form>
             <input type="hidden" class="adore1" name="aime" value="${post.id}">
             <input type="button" class="adore2" value="J'aime">
         </form>
     </div>
     <c:if test="${ post.adore == 0 || post.adore == 1 }">
     <div class="nbreAimes"><p><span class="nbrAdore">${ post.adore }</span> personne aime ça</p></div>
     </c:if>

     <c:if test="${ post.adore != 0 && post.adore != 1 }">
     <div class="nbreAimes"><p><span class="nbrAdore">${ post.adore }</span> personnes aiment ça</p></div>
     </c:if>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".adore2").click(function(){
        var aime = $(this).parent().find(".adore1").val()
        var value = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find(".nbrAdore").text()
        alert(value)

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: {aime:aime},
            url:"acceuilServlet",
            success:function(result){
                alert(result)
                // this is the line where i am having a problem 
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find(".nbrAdore").html(result)     
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is that when I click my input ( button ) with class "adore2", the number of likes ( in span with class "nbrAdore" ) has to increment in my database.

I used alert to see if everything is fine just like any begginer and I will explain by an example.

If number of likes is 14, my value ( var value ) is fine, I get it, my alert shows 14, and my alert(result) shows 15 which means that the treatement in my controller is done correctly, but I can't see this in my view, I believe my problem is here and I dont know how to solve it :

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings().find(".nbrAdore").html(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `.siblings()` is a collection of elements. It's hard to tell on which element `.find()` would be applyed, if applyed at all.

So what about removing that uncertainty and try to find the target element from `.aimerSection` right away?

```
$(this).closest(".aimerSection").find(".nbrAdore").html(result);
```

---

**EDIT**

Seems like your `.nbrAdore` isn't a child of `.aimerSection`.

Look in the code inspector where that really is located.

Comment: I undertand your point, but your solution is not working too :( .

Comment: mmm... Ok. Two tests: **1)** `console.log($(this).closest(".aimerSection").find(".nbrAdore").length);` Should give 1. **2)** `console.log(result);` verify the result.

Comment: mm yes! it gave me a strange result.. as i told i get the value result correct! but the length of the element gives me 0..

Comment: So it doesn't find the element. Look if the class is spelled correctly... And if the element is a child of `.aimerSection` like it looks like in what you posted.

Comment: Another test would be to check if there is one of those in the whole document: `console.log($(document).find(".nbrAdore‌​").length);`

Comment: Well it gives a result that is true! I have 5 posts in my landing page and it gives 5 .. 
And yes everythings is spelled right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162690/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-taouben).

Answer (score 0):

The context for `this` is changing in the ajax call. It changes to the `jqXHR` of the ajax call. You can save `$(this)` to a variable before and use that variable in the callback:

```
var self = $(this);
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: {aime:aime},
        url:"acceuilServlet",
        success:function(result){
            alert(result)
            // this is the line where i am having a problem 
            self.parent().parent().siblings().find(".nbrAdore").html(result)     
        }
    })
```

But the better approach would be to save the elem itself, because you are using it twice:

```
var elem = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find(".nbrAdore");
var value = elem.text();
....
success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
    elem.html(result);
}
```